# How to use MKLocalSearch In MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mklocalsearch

i am using MKLocalSearch in MKMapView..I am implementing as follow

```
extension MYClass: SendLocationDelegate{

    func sendCoOrdinates(loccoordinate:CLLocation, placemark:CLPlacemark){

        println(" Google VC coordinate is as \(loccoordinate.coordinate.longitude) \(loccoordinate.coordinate.latitude)")
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:loccoordinate.coordinate.latitude, longitude: loccoordinate.coordinate.longitude)
        let theSpan : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01)
        let theRegion : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: theSpan)
        self.mapView.setRegion(theRegion, animated: false)

        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

        search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response: MKLocalSearchResponse!,
            error: NSError!) in

            if error != nil {
                println("Error occured in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else if response.mapItems.count == 0 {

                println("No matches found")

            } else {

                println("Matches found")

                println("\(response)")

            }
        })



    }


}
```

**Output: Google VC coordinate is as 72.8561644 19.0176147
Error occured in search: The operation couldn’t be completed. (MKErrorDomain error 1.)** Why is this happening?

EDITED: however when i change request as

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
 request.naturalLanguageQuery = "india"
 //request.region = mapView.region
 let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
```

I get the good response as

> {
>       boundingRegion = "";
>       mapItems =     (
>           " {\n    isCurrentLocation = 0;\n    name = India;\n    placemark = \"India, India @
>   <+23.04117260,+78.89180550> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion
>   (identifier:'<+21.84329084,+82.78786665> radius 2237301.34',
>   center:<+21.84329084,+82.78786665>, radius:2237301.34m)\";\n}"
>       ); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working fine..Just you did a mistake on request that doesnot contains a naturalLanguageQuery as

```
 let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
 request.region = mapView.region
 let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
```

In this case `request.naturalLanguageQuery` is set it to nil....so you got (MKErrorDomain error 1) of unknown type.Look on  Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearchRequest_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKLocalSearchRequest/region)`naturalLanguageQuery` cannot contain nil value...So make a request with it

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
 request.naturalLanguageQuery = "india"
 let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
```

You can use `region` parameter to narrow the list of search results to those inside or close to the specified region. Specifying a region does not guarantee that the results will all be inside the region. It is merely a hint to the search engine. So `region` can act as an optional here. Or you can make request as for better results as

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "india"
request.region = mapView.region
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
```